# How to use compile_commands.json in fish shell?

Tags: shell, compiler-errors, gtk, clang, fish

I have fish shell installed as the default shell on my fedora machine. I recently switched to nvim and I am using deoplete-clang2 for autocomplete.

But it's only completing the names of the header files. So based on this [issue](https://github.com/tweekmonster/deoplete-clang2/issues/15) I tried creating a `compile_commands.json` file.

```
[
    {
        "directory" : "/mnt/Work/Learn/Gtk/Official",
        "command" : " /usr/bin/bash echo \"/usr/bin/clang (pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o main main.c (pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)\"",
        "file" : "/mnt/Work/Learn/Gtk/Official/main.c"
    }
]
```

But when I run `clang-check main.c` to verify the commands the following errors are thrown.

```
error: unsupported option '--cflags'
error: unsupported option '--libs'
warning: (pkg-config: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
warning: gtk+-3.0): 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
warning: (pkg-config: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
warning: gtk+-3.0): 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from main.c:2:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30:10: fatal error: 'gdk/gdk.h' file not found
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Error while processing /mnt/Work/Learn/Gtk/Official/main.c.
```

So how do I fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly executing *bash*, not fish.

```
"command" : " /usr/bin/bash echo \"[...]
```

You can change that by using "/usr/bin/fish" instead of bash (adjust the path if that's not where you have installed fish).

Alternatively, you just need to change the `()` to `$()` - that's where the error comes from. `command1 (command2 arg1 arg2)` isn't valid syntax in bash, and will just be passed as-is to command1 (i.e. it'll receive `(command2`, `arg1` and `arg2)` as its arguments).

Change it to

```
"command" : " /usr/bin/bash echo \"/usr/bin/clang $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o main main.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)\""
```

and it should work. (Note the `$`s)

---

If you do decide to use fish, note that `pkg-config` expects its output to be split on spaces, which fish doesn't do (only newlines). So you'd need to pipe it to `string split " "`, like

```
(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 | string split " ")
```

Comment: Still throws an error ```warning: echo: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
warning: /usr/bin/clang $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o main main.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0): 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''
Error while processing /mnt/Work/Learn/Gtk/Official/main.c.
```

Comment: In that case, it looks like your clang invocation is wrong or `pkg-config` doesn't work. Try executing the `pkg-config` invocations in a terminal and see if the output matches what you expect. Also check if the `echo` is actually necessary - I don't know deoplete, so I'm not sure if this should print a command to be executed or be the command directly. In the latter case, remove the `echo`.

Comment: pkg-config works perfectly onna terminal, and everything works as expected if i run the pkg-config command manually and substitute the output in the command.